# How can I add "description bars" in plot without committing to a theme?

Tags: plotting

Look at the attached picture. How do I add the bars specifying C without committing to a theme like PlotTheme -> "Detailed"?[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [`PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) ?

Comment: Thank you very much!